# How can i swap one term in img src on all dom images using javascript / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to swap all img src /products/210x110/foo-bar-foo-front.jpg to /products/210x110/bar-foo-bar-angle.jpg & apply it to every image in the dom.

My current code works but applies the src url from the first image in the dom to all img src attributes:

i need to just replace 1 word...

```
//toggle image angles
var img = $("div.product-image a img");
$('div#image-angle-switch').toggle(function() {
    $(this).html('<span></span> Angle view ')
    switch_to_low_fi();
}, function() {
    $(this).html('<span></span> Front view')
    img.attr("src", img.attr("src").replace("front", "angle"));
});
$('div#image-angle-switch').click(function() {
    img.attr("src", img.attr("src").replace("toggle"));
});
```

Could i create an array of each img src, swap one word and reapply to every img?

```
var tn_array = $("div.product-image a img").map(function() {

    return $(this).attr("src");
});

for (var i=0; i<tn_array.length; i++) {
    console.log(tn_array[i]);
}
```

Got my array but how should i apply it? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why map it? Just swap it like the click.

Comment: so no need for an array? it's replacing all images with first img src rather than just replacing 1 word.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? it's clearly old due to your use of .toggle

Comment: yes. 1.5. Legacy code i'm working with... :/

Comment: so loop over each image. You're already looping over them using .map, why not change the source there?

Comment: could you show me how i can modify the src using the loop, that's the bit i can't get...

Comment: `/*return */$(this).attr("src","someothersrc...");`

Comment: `$.each( 'img', function(){ var src = $(this).attr('src'); src = src.replace("front", "angle"); $(this).attr('src', src);});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over each image and change it's src.

```
$('#image-angle-switch').data("view", "front").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data("view") == "front") {
        $this.html('<span></span> Angle view ').data("view","angle");

        // this does the looping
        $("div.product-image a img").attr("src",function (i, src) {
            return src.replace("front", "angle");
        });
    } else {
        $this.html('<span></span> Front view ').data("view", "front");

        // this does the looping
        $("div.product-image a img").attr("src", function (i, src) {
            return src.replace("angle", "front");
        });
    }
});
```

Also replaced the old depreciated toggle method. Could be made dryer though

Comment: Just for curiosity, let me ask you why did you use `var $this = $(this);` ? I mean, ok to use a variable to store `$(this)` but seams a little off to store it with almost the same name. Besides the typography there is anything to do with performance?

Comment: It's a very tiny optimization in this case, but the purpose is to not create a new jquery object multiple times when you don't need to. Just one of my coding habits, but it's not a bad habit to have

Comment: i get - Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'replace'

Comment: just out of interest, did you add the i for the loop' ?

Comment: No, it's just an argument that gets passed to the iterator function by jquery. we dont' use it, but we have to accept it to get the second argument which contains the src of the image we're currently modifying.